# Inheritance with large class hierarchy

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, architecture

Suppose you are creating a project that involves a large class hierarchy, which involves fairly complicated __init__ methods that call parents all the way from leaf classes to the root, like a taxonomy of life.

There could be many parameters that every `Organism` has, shared among all of them, along with any specialized ones down the hierarchy.

Suppose during development you realize you may need to add another parameter to the constructor of an Organism, which every Organism should be able to be constructed with. What is the best way to structure the classes to add this parameter to the class hierarchy? I can think of two ways:

1. add the new parameter to every single __init__ method, and every call to super().__init__

pros:

- explicit

cons:

- involves lots of likely tedious manual editing
- bulky
- can't set defaults at upper level classes

example:

```
class Organism:
    def __init__(a=1, b=2, ...):
        ...

...

class HomoSapiens(Homo):
    def __init__(a=None, b=None, ..., c=1, d=2):
        ...
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b, ..., c=c)

class CanisFamiliaris(Canis):
    def __init__(a=None, b=None, ..., e=1, f=2):
        ...
        super().__init__(a=a, b=b, ..., e=e)
```

2. instead define the class structure to use *args or **kwargs in every __init__, and pass these up the hierarchy

pros:

- easier to write
- potentially makes clear what classes are the "characteristic" classes for a parameter
- seems simpler

cons:

- implicit
- unclear as to what parameters are available to, for example, a HomoSapiens by nature of being an Organism

example:

```
class Organism:
    def __init__(a=1, b=2, ...):
        ...

...

class HomoSapiens(Homo):
    def __init__(c=1, d=2, **kwargs):
        ...
        super().__init__(c=c, **kwargs)

class CanisFamiliaris(Canis):
    def __init__(e=1, f=2, **kwargs):
        ...
        super().__init__(e=e, **kwargs)
```

The second option is tempting, because it involves much less editing in the case of signature changes, but is it sacrificing too much in clarity?

Comment: Have you tried the Builder Pattern?

Comment: Option 3 - avoid class hierarchies. Don't use OOP for classification/taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a single right answer to this one; it's really a judgment call depending on how your code will get used. As you said yourself, it's a tradeoff between readability and maintainability. So which is more important/efficient in your case?
If you anticipate needing to go back and add/modify properties in the class structure a lot, then I'd lean towards option 2. If that's not the case, and you have team members that need to be able to read your code, then maybe option 1 could be better. But even in that case, if those people also have to maintain it in addition to just understand it, then I'd lean towards option 2 anyways and give them maintainable code to work with. There are better ways to improve readability without compromising mainatainability. Maybe you add some extra methods/parameters in the root class to help people find that implicit info that they would usually look for in the subclass definitions. For example, to find what properties and methods are distinctive of any class in your hierarchy, write a single method in the root class, something like:

```
class Organism:
    @classmethod
    def distinctProperties(cls) -> set:
        """Set of 'new' properties and method names for the class not present in its parent class."""
        return set(cls.__dict__) - set([cls.__bases__[0].__dict__)
```

You can modify that method a bit if there's multiple inheritance in your hierarchy.